# Flex does not recognize identifiers

Tags: c, parsing, flex-lexer

I am trying to implement a very simple parser using flex. I am currently stuck in the ID recognition. That is my code:

```
ID [a−zA−Z_][a−zA−Z0−9_]*
...
{ID} { printf( "An identifier: %s\n", yytext ); return TOK_ID;}
```

However what I get is only the first letter of the identifier, for example if I try to parse:

```
int _underscore ;
```

The result is:

```
An identifier: _
```

Any advice?

EDIT:

With a more accurate analysis I have figured out that the code is able to recognize only the id with a,z,A,Z,_, that are the explicit characters in the regular expression. I did not find anything like that online, is that a bug?

EDIT2:

If I modify the code in that way all work

```
ID [a−zA−Z_][a−zA−Z0−9_]*
...
[a−zA−Z_][a−zA−Z0−9_]* { printf( "An identifier: %s\n", yytext ); return TOK_ID;}
```

According to the documentation it should work also in the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a character encoding issue.  In your copy-and-pasted source code, the things that *look* like ASCII hyphens (`-`, code U+2D) in your definition of ID:

```
ID [a−zA−Z_][a−zA−Z0−9_]*
```

aren't.  Instead they're unicode minus signs (`−`, U+2212).  If you replace the incorrect minus signs with the correct hyphens, the line will look like:

```
ID [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

Depending on your font, if you look *very* closely, you may see a difference between the `−` in the first version and the `-` in the second.

Anyway, replace your `ID` definition with the second version above (or else retype it from scratch, and all should be well.

Comment: Ouch — that's a horrible extra complexity to have to deal with.  It'll be catching people depressingly (and probably increasingly) often.